# Next book in learning Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation, research

I have just finished the book *Introductory Algebraic Number Theory* by Kenneth S. Williams and Saban Alaca. My aim is to reach to graduate level to do research, especially in one or more of the following fields:

> Algebraic Number Theory;
>
> Elliptic Curves;
>
> Complex Multiplication;
>
> The Class Numbers of Ray Class Fields of Imaginary Quadratic Fields;
>
> Arithmetically Exceptional Mappings.

but articles are not only too advanced to study after Alaca's book, but also I don't think that they are readable by just studying Alaca's book at all for a self-learner like me. Please someone tell me a book for Algebraic Number Theory more advanced than Alaca's book but readable esp. for self-learning . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Silverman's rational points on elliptic curves/the arithmetic of elliptic curves should be good for you. Maybe start with the former if you haven't come across elliptic curves in the past.

Comment: @Alexandros, I've finished the former, but not the latter one! Can I study Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* by just Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter 0* as prerequisite?

Comment: If you have read rational points on elliptic curves, then you should be prepared to study the arithmetic on elliptic curves.